# postgreSQL 9.4 how to rollback from trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have the function  insert_val that inserts some values into some tables. These tables have triggers that raises exception when something is wrong. How can I rollback the function whenever a trigger raises exception and go to the next curs1 is this possible? Thanks in advance

```
res :='start';
OPEN curs1 FOR SELECT temp3.fid FROM temp3; 
LOOP 

FETCH curs1 INTO fidVar;
EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
BEGIN
if raise_exception then
rollback;
end if;
perform insert_val(fidVar,startDate,endDate);    
END;
END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot `ROLLBACK` from a trigger or function, because transaction control is not possible within functions.

What you actually seem to want is to skip and continue after an exception. You can do this using `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION` blocks in PL/PgSQL, [per the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html).  Internally this uses subtransactions just like `SAVEPOINT` and `ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT`.